# Reverse the order of characters within words with five letters or more

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, reverse

I'm new to Java and I'm still learning. As a part of my learning I took a challenge to write a program that will take a string, and check if there are any words, that are 5 or more in length and if so, it will flip the chars in the 5+ long words. The challenge was to do it without using Collections.reverse(list) or StringBuilder.

My idea was, I'd say simple to write 2 methods.
Main will split the string, and iterate by each string array index looking for 5+ long words, and method called 'reverse' would be triggered inside 'if' condition. Look like this one works okay.
For the reverse method idea was to split the word to an array, and then with help of 2 nested 'for' loops iterate by indexes of 'ori' and auxiliary 'rev' arrays to assign value of index ori[i] to index rev[j].

So beginning with i=0 and j=arr.length-1 will result with assigning value "s" out of sentence word in ori[0] to rev[7], then "e" from ori[1] to rev[6], and so on, so the result would be [e, c, n, e, t, n, e, s]

Instead I get output like this:

```
[This, [e, e, e, e, e, e, e, e], will, [n, n, n, n, n, n, n], [s, s, s, s, s], with, more, than, five, [., ., ., ., ., ., ., .]]
```

I tried to fix that many ways, but so far my logic fails. Could someone explain me please, what am I doing wrong, how did I screw that apparently simple logic?

I'll figure out how to display this as a regular sentence without square brackets and commas later so this is no issue so far.

The code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        String original = "This sentence will contain words with more than five letters.";
        String[] splitter = original.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < splitter.length; i++){
            if (splitter[i].length() >= 5){
                splitter[i] = reverse(splitter[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitter));

    }
    public static String reverse (String s){
        String [] ori = s.split("");
        String [] rev = new String[ori.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < rev.length; i++) {
            for (int j = rev.length-1; j >=0; j--) {
                rev[j] = ori[i];
            }
        }
        s = Arrays.toString(rev);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Please be understading for a newbie :)

I tried to modify this part:

```
public static String reverse (String s){
        String [] ori = s.split("");
        String [] rev = new String[ori.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < rev.length; i++) {
            for (int j = rev.length-1; j >=0; j--) {
                rev[j] = ori[i];
```

by swapping i/j, rev[i] = ori[j], --j, j > 0 and many others, mostly blind shots looking for some inspiration where my logic fails.

Comment: Hint : you can do the reversing with one `for` loop and modify `i` and `j` within it at once. Hint 2 : your code right now is effectively filling the `rev` array with the last character from `ori` array and you iterating over `rev` array `rev.length` times.

Comment: "Hint : you can do the reversing with one for loop and modify i and j within it at once" - thanks, I'll try!
"Hint 2 : your code right now is effectively filling the rev array with the last character from ori array and you iterating over rev array rev.length times." - I asked question the the duck why does it fills the last letters only, and found this answer just a minute after writting the post, thanks!

Comment: Nitpick: `split` is quite expensive operation to use for dividing the word into characters (because it uses regex). You should use `getChars`. Bonus point: certain characters (like emojis) will not look anywhere near the right way when simply reversing like that.

Comment: Thanks @M.Prokhorov I'll remmeber that :)
I'll try to modify whole code later on to use getChars then :)

Comment: @MichałKrzywański following your hit it looks like this:

`public static String reverse (String s){
        String [] ori = s.split("");
        String [] rev = new String[ori.length];
        for (int i = 0, j = rev.length - i - 1; i < rev.length; i++, j--) {
            rev[j] = ori[i];
            }
        s = Arrays.toString(rev);
        return s;
`
And it works just fine, I had no idea I can modify 2 variables in one for loop so this is really valuable hit for me :) anyway Ammar's solution looks waay better so I'll stick with his :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy Pawel Niewolak, the issue is with your reverse function.

Depending on your requirements use that:

```
 public static String reverse(String s) {
        String[] ori = s.split("");
        String[] rev = new String[ori.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < rev.length; i++) {
            rev[i] = ori[rev.length - i - 1];
        }
        s = "";
        for (String str : rev) {
            s += str;
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: `The challenge was to do it without using Collections.reverse(list) or StringBuilder.`

Comment: okay  let me edit that

Comment: Oh man, this is genious!
I can't upvote unfortunately:
Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Comment: No issue.  have fun with it

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibility that uses the existing array of characters.

- create the array using `String.toCharArray()`
- iterate half-way thru the array, simply swapping the end characters moving inward.
- then since the String constructor takes an array of characters as an argument, return `new String(array)`

```
public static String reverse(String s) {
    char[] array = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i <array.length/2; i++) {
        char ch = array[i];
        array[i] = array[array.length-i-1];
        array[array.length-i-1] = ch;
    }
    return new String(array);
}
```

Note that for even length strings, the middle two characters are swapped. For odd length strings, the middle character is untouched.